# Downloading m3u8 videos from Header based CDN

Tags: automated-testing

I need to automate download of m3u8 stream, any command line / browser automation plugins that can be easily plugged into Selenium to do the job?

The test scope is open a web page, accept the cookies, initiate video playback, capture video stream. Then compare the captured stream to examine quality.

I've tried automation using external tools such as ffmpeg but can't seem to be able to get the `-headers` flag to work from command line.